# Date Picker Today Option In WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

Is there any property , option available in the date picker control so that if user want to select today from any date from current date ?
e.g if user is view current month of last year then he has the option to select current date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just see this link and how they are implementing the Today button in the Datepicker WPF Toolkit). This link is from the WPFToolkit discussion forum. May be this will help you.

http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=85516

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no option that there is a button directly in the control.
You can use a button outside the control, or something like this to set the current date.

Or you build a custom control....

Answer (score 0):

I just hacked together a simple example. It is VS 2010. www.mbgr.de/CurrentDateWpf.zip.
No warranty at all on this one. Use at your own risk :-)

Comment: A separate button , I Have the idea of it , but I want to look for the solution in which current date selection is embaded in the date picker control.

Comment: Dead link. Yet another example of why a "link-only" answer is bad.